# PHP: strtotime does not shows correct value

Tags: php, mysql

from mysql i got `2012-11 05-05 12:39:1` but if i used `date('n-Y', strtotime(2012-1105-05 12:39:1));` it shows `1-1970`

any idea what's problem

Comment: Even *I* can't tell what that date is supposed to be. Not surprised PHP can't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably isn't a valid format in that case:

```
2012-1105-05
      ^ ?? - what notation is this
```

See all valid formats **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)**.